# If a finite sequence of elementary row operations is performed on A, the resulting matrix is $PA$($P$ is the transforming matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

If $E_1,E_2,...E_q$ are the elementary matrices corresponding to a finite sequence $S$ of elementary row operations, then we call $P:=E_qE_{q-1}...E_2E_1$ the **transforming matrix** corresponding to $S$.

> **Theorem:** If a finite sequence $S$ of elementary row operations is performed on any matrix $A$, the resulting matrix is $PA$ where $P$ is the transforming matrix corresponding to $S$.

Trivially, I can see that the matrix obtained from $A$ after performing the first elementary row operation (from $S$) is $E_1A$. The matrix obtained after performing the second elementary row is $E_2(E_1A)$, and so on.

However, I wanted a formal proof for the theorem (if there is one).

Comment: Isn't that a direct result of transitivity of matrix products? $(A.B).C = A.(B.C)$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan What i want to know is whether that simple explanation is enough as a formal proof.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I thought about your comment using which I can get a trivial yet "formal" proof for the stated theorem. Do you mind submitting the comment as an answer to the question instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix obtained after performing the sequence $S$ of row operations on $A$ is
$$E_q(E_{q-1}(E_{q-2}...(E_2(E_1A))...).$$
Using transitivity of matrix products,
[as mentioned in @DhanviSreenivasan 's comment: $A(B\cdot C)=(A\cdot B)C$]
$$E_q(E_{q-1}(E_{q-2}...(E_2(E_1A))...)=(E_qE_{q-1}...E_2E_1)A$$
If $P$ is the transforming matrix corresponding to $S$, then $P=E_qE_{q-1}...E_2E_1$.
$\therefore$ the resulting matrix after the transformation is $PA$